# Can't export Kotlin Compose project. Fails with error: ComposePluginRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I've created a Kotlin application with Compose desktop and I'm attempting to export a `.jar`. But I get this error:

```
Kotlin: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposePluginRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposePluginRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli_base(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:689)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:587)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:194)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt)
```

My `build.gradle.kts` is as follows:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.5.10"
}

group = "com.jfresh"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

dependencies {
    // Note, if you develop a library, you should use compose.desktop.common.
    // compose.desktop.currentOs should be used in launcher-sourceSet
    // (in a separate module for demo project and in testMain).
    // With compose.desktop.common you will also lose @Preview functionality
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
    implementation("com.seanproctor:data-table-material:0.5.1")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0")
    implementation("com.darkrockstudios:mpfilepicker:3.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")

}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "GroupExplorer"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

And `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.9.20
compose.version=1.5.10
```

I'm using Kotlin 1.9.20. I've checked [the following](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin#kts) table and `1.5.10` appears to be the correct Compose version for my version of Kotlin.

I've even created a new hello world project, and attempted to build a `.jar` and I get the same results.

I've also tried a different version of Kotlin and it's matching Compose. The error remains.

Can't seem to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned that compose apps shouldn't be deployed in this way. Instead, use the Gradle tasks. I'm not sure if similar exists for Maven.

In IntelliJ Double tap `CTRL`, and type `gradle package`. You'll see multiple options for `msi`, `dmg` and `deb`. In my case I selected `gradle packageMsi`.

[image]

This successfully built an installer, and the application.